# How do I calculate bounded integral?

Tags: integration

It's given interval $I=[0,4]\times[0,8]$, how do I put bounds if I have 
$\int_{I}( −2xy^4+x^2y^2) d(x,y)$. Is $\int_{0}^{4}(\int_{0}^{8} −2xy^4+x^2y^2 dy)dx=-4554752/45$ correct?

Comment: This is a correct answer. You can use wolframalpha to check such things: (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B-2+x+y%5E4%2Bx%5E2+y%5E2,%7Bx,0,4%7D,%7By,0,8%7D%5D). Which method did you use to find this value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct; this is a consequence of [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini.27s_theorem_for_integrable_functions). I don't know what your knowledge is measure theory is like, but this is the case in which $f(x,y) = x^2y^2 - 2xy^4$ is measurable and is $([0,4]\times [0,8])-$integrable (it's sufficient that $f$ is continuous on $I$).

Therefore as stated in the theorem you can go straight for partial integration, your choice which among $x$,$y$ to start with:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^8\left(\int_0^4(x^2y^2-2xy^4)dx\right)dy =\\
\int_{0}^8\left[ \frac{x^3}{3}y^2 -2\frac{x^2}{2}y^4\right]_{x=0}^{x=4}dy =\\
\int_{0}^8\left( \frac{64}{3}\,y^2 - 16\,y^4\right)dy=\\
\left[ \frac{64}{3}\frac{y^3}{3} -16\frac{y^5}{5}  \right]_{y=0}^{y=8} =\ -\frac{4554752}{45}.
\end{align}
$$

I first started with $x$; and your answer is correct.